# NVD API for multiple CVEs

Tags: cve

While looking into specs of [NVD APIs](https://nvd.nist.gov/developers/vulnerabilities), the documentation mentions `The CVE API is used to easily retrieve information on a single CVE or a collection of CVE from the NVD.` However, the API documentation does not mention any means of providing data for multiple CVEs of choice in a single request. My requirement is to fetch data of 700 CVEs in a single API request.

They also have [data feeds](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds) which they discourage from using and plan to discontinue it from Sep 2023. In addition to these limitations, they also have [rate limiting](https://nvd.nist.gov/developers/start-here) which prohibits more than 50 requests in 30s.

Currently, my option is to go with data feeds which are going to stay for another few months, but wanted to know if anyone is familiar with any option where multiple CVEs can be retrieved in one API call.

Answer (score 0):

Got in touch with NVD team on their email and got the response posted below. Currently such option does not exist, but would come up in future when they plan for next iteration. No ETA provided.

> This feature, or something similar, has been requested multiple times
> from quite a few sources. We do not have plans to add features to the
> existing 2.0 APIs, but we are consolidating and tracking feedback and
> feature requests for when we begin the next iteration of the APIs.
> This feature is certainly on the list for consideration.
>
> For performing larger dataset comparisons we advise using the APIs to
> create a local mirror of NVD data and then simply keep that updated
> instead. This is a way of avoiding the rate limits for more frequent
> query needs (See
> https://nvd.nist.gov/developers/start-here#divBestPractices).